# Модули JavaScript, как правильно импортировать

Tags: javascript, импорт

Предположим в главном .js файле я импортирую 2 модуля. В каждом из этих модулей я использую одну и ту же библиотеку, поэтому в каждом из них я прописываю необходимые для нее import'ы. Означает ли это что при импорте этих модулей в главный .js файл код библиотеки скопируется 2 раза? Или js умный и поймет что это одинаковые импорты и не будет второй раз импортировать библиотеку в главный js?
Использую WebPack для сборки.

Comment: Наверное, стоит уточнить в вопросе: речь идет о бандлерах, или о стандартном импорте без участия утилит-сборщиков. Сборщики нередко трансформируют код (зависит от их настроек), например из ESM делают UMD... при такой трансформации, вопрос обретает совсем другой смысл :)

Comment: использую WebPack

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не содержит технических подробностей требуемых для однозначного ответа (таких как: формат модулей, способ их импорта, используемые инструменты сборки и их конфигурация, условия воспроизведения ситуации, и т.д.). В текущей формулировке, вопрос предполагает обобщенные/размытые ответы, которые не принесут пользу сообществу.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от того, как происходит сборка. При нормальной сборке дублирования быть не должно, если только сборка не происходит в 2 библиотеки, каждая из которых включает общую.

Comment: Сборка может и не происходить, если не пользоваться бандлером (который конечно объявит экспортируемое значение так чтобы его можно было переиспользовать... оптимизашки). Вот то что происходит при множественном импорте одного и того же значения из es-модуля без участия сборщиков, стандартным способом - действительно интересно.

Comment: @yar85, без бандлера каждый модуль - отдельный файл. При каждом открытии страницы каждый скрипт будет загружаться (или доставаться из кэша) только по 1 разу.

Comment: А если экспортированное из модуля значение при этом вычисляемое (например, `export default new Foo()`) - то оно будет перевычисляться при каждом импорте, т.е. не будет нигде кэшироваться, правильно? _//Это я про тот же стандартный импорт например браузером, то есть без бандлера._

Comment: @yar85, неправильно. Импорты-экспорты имеют ссылочную связь через слоты, это даже не близко к инлайну кода. В js вообще нет инлайна кода. Что один раз вычислилось, то и будет лежать.

Comment: Хм, мне казалось это только от скоупа (импортирующей стороны) зависит - про слоты не знал, надо будет почитать-изучить. Спасибо!

Comment: @yar85, возможно я не очень точно назвал или вспомнил название из каких-нибудь v8 internals. Но они обещали повысить производительность за счёт того, что при компиляции скрипта будут исключать лексический поиск имени и делать связь напрямую. И связь по стандарту ссылочная - одно из немногих мест, где такое существует в js (импорты, nonstrict arguments и с натяжкой замыкание).